# btn-primary disappears in small layouts?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a submit-button on my page (http://mbaas.redirectme.net/foo.dyalog )

```
<input type="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Anmelden">
```

While testing responsive layout, I noted that it disappeared when the page got smaller than 600px. It's probably not a probleme because  also submits the page, but I'm wondering if Bootstrap decided small pages wouldn't need a submit-button or if I made a fault???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fixed footer is on top of the button.
You can solve this by adding the height of the fixed footer as extra margin or padding at the body.

```
body{
    margin-bottom:46px; // or: padding-bottom:46px;
}
```

I would advise to add 20 more, so you also have a small whitespace underneath the button.

Comment: Thanks very much to both of you - it did not occur to me to search behind the footer! :((   code.prio was first to answer, but the idea of adding margin to the body (instead of the input) seems better (since I may get the same problem on other pages, too, and this is quite general...)

Answer (score 1):

Its actually in there . In resolution of the 320*480 it got hidden . But if you inspect and add `margin-bottom: 50%;` to the `<input>`
field it got visible. means , its just needs some extra space to show up . Nothing else. Please let us know.